# How to properly re-format spaces in inline monospace?

Tags: latex, texttt

I don't want the whitespaces in inline monospaced text to be monospaced. They should have the width of the normal font. The `\intexttt` (as in the example below) does this but it seems to be unnecessarily complicated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\intexttt}[1]{%
  \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg%
  \texttt{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{ }{\textnormal{ }}}%
  \restoreexpandmode%
}

\begin{document} 
\noindent
What does \texttt{SELECT FROM} do? \\
What does \texttt{SELECT} \texttt{FROM} do? \\
What does \intexttt{SELECT FROM} do?
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Is there a better way?